# Keep only "cluster" with the highest number of elements

Tags: r, classification

Start with the example data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("France", "Spain"), class = "factor"), 
    Car = structure(c(6L, 17L, 7L, 18L, 4L, 13L, 20L, 5L, 14L, 
    21L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 9L, 12L, 16L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 9L, 12L, 19L, 
    3L, 10L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Audi_1_EON", "Audi_2_EON", 
    "Ferrari_1_EOD", "Fiat_1_EOD", "Fiat_1_EON", "Mazda_1_EOD", 
    "Mazda_1_EON", "Mercedes_1_EOD", "Mercedes_1_EON", "Mercedes_2_EOD", 
    "Nexia_1_EOD", "Nexia_1_EON", "Opel_1_EOD", "Opel_1_EON", 
    "Peugeot_1_EOD", "Peugeot_1_EON", "Porsche_2_EOD", "Porsche_2_EON", 
    "Tico_1_EON", "VW_1_EOD", "VW_1_EON"), class = "factor"), 
    ValueOfComp = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L)), .Names = c("Country", "Car", "ValueOfComp"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

In the presented `data` we have two different countries in the first column. In the next column we can find the cars assigned to each country and in the last column is the number of cluster.

I would like to keep in the table only a single cluster for each of the country. It has to be the biggest cluster for each country. Let's take France as an example. Two clusters (`13` and `14`) are assigned to this country. It's obvious that cluster 14 contains more elements/cars. In that case I would like to keep cluster 14 and remove cluster 13 from the data.

The presented data is only an example. My real data is a massive table so I believe in some cases it may happen that the clusters contain the same number of elements so it doesn't matter which one will stay with the data.

Comment: what happens if there are two clusters of equal size? keep them both, or choose randomly one?

Comment: I mentioned it in the last paragraph. Choose randomly. That was so easy for you :).

Comment: here is an approach below which selects the first group by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

data[ValueOfComp %in% setDT(data)[,rle(ValueOfComp), Country][
                                  ,values[which.max(lengths)], Country]$V1,]

    Country            Car ValueOfComp
 1:  France     Fiat_1_EOD          14
 2:  France     Opel_1_EOD          14
 3:  France       VW_1_EOD          14
 4:  France     Fiat_1_EON          14
 5:  France     Opel_1_EON          14
 6:  France       VW_1_EON          14
 7:   Spain Mercedes_1_EOD          15
 8:   Spain    Nexia_1_EOD          15
 9:   Spain  Peugeot_1_EOD          15
10:   Spain Mercedes_1_EON          15
11:   Spain    Nexia_1_EON          15
12:   Spain  Peugeot_1_EON          15
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` you could do:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Country, ValueOfComp) %>%
  mutate(size = n()) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(size == max(size), ValueOfComp == max(ValueOfComp))

Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
Groups: Country [2]

   Country            Car ValueOfComp  size
    (fctr)         (fctr)       (int) (int)
1   France     Fiat_1_EOD          14     6
2   France     Opel_1_EOD          14     6
3   France       VW_1_EOD          14     6
4   France     Fiat_1_EON          14     6
5   France     Opel_1_EON          14     6
6   France       VW_1_EON          14     6
7    Spain Mercedes_1_EOD          16     6
8    Spain    Nexia_1_EOD          16     6
9    Spain  Peugeot_1_EOD          16     6
10   Spain Mercedes_1_EON          16     6
11   Spain    Nexia_1_EON          16     6
12   Spain     Tico_1_EON          16     6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `plyr` package and `subset` to get,

```
ddply(dat, "Country", subset, ValueOfComp == count(ValueOfComp)$x[which.max(count(ValueOfComp)$freq)])
#   Country            Car ValueOfComp
#1   France     Fiat_1_EOD          14
#2   France     Opel_1_EOD          14
#3   France       VW_1_EOD          14
#4   France     Fiat_1_EON          14
#5   France     Opel_1_EON          14
#6   France       VW_1_EON          14
#7    Spain Mercedes_1_EOD          15
#8    Spain    Nexia_1_EOD          15
#9    Spain  Peugeot_1_EOD          15
#10   Spain Mercedes_1_EON          15
#11   Spain    Nexia_1_EON          15
#12   Spain  Peugeot_1_EON          15
```